# How to change libdirs priority in premake?

Tags: linker, premake

I have the following lines in my premake4.lua file

```
platforms { "x32", "x64" }
...
libdirs { "../deps/linux/lib64" }
```

Then the generated Makefile will contain:

```
LDFLAGS   += -m64 -L/usr/lib64 -L../deps/linux/lib64
```

Is it possible to prioritize my custom library dir?
I mean I want the following line:

```
LDFLAGS   += -m64 -L../deps/linux/lib64 -L/usr/lib64
```

I'm using premake4 but I can switch to premake5 if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Premake4, you can add this to your project file:

```
premake.gcc.platforms.x64.ldflags = "-L../deps/linux/lib64 -L/usr/lib64"
```

In Premake5, you can do this:

```
premake.tools.gcc.libraryDirectories.architecture.x86_64 = { "-L../deps/linux/lib64", "-L/usr/lib64" }
```

Though it would clearly be better if you didn't have to do that. If you [could open an issue ticket](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues) and link it to this discussion I can look into swapping those variables around in the code.